# Get duplicate documents based on duplicate nested type

Tags: java, elasticsearch

Good day guys.
I have a document type "generalTask" with an array of nested documents called "completeUser".

Here is the mapping :

```
{
    "generalTask": {
        "properties": {
            "id": {
                "type": "long"
            },
            "completeUser": {
                "type": "nested",
                "properties": {
                    "completeTime": {
                        "type": "long"
                    },
                    "userId": {
                        "type": "long"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And now, we have two documents.

e.g.

```
{
    "_source": {
        "id": 1001,
        "completeUser": [
            {
                "userId": 1,
                "completeTime": 100
            },
            {
                "userId": 1,
                "completeTime": 300
            },
            {
                "userId":1,
                "completeTime": 500
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

and

```
{
    "_source": {
        "id": 1002,
        "completeUser": [
            {
                "userId": 1,
                "completeTime": 200
            },
            {
                "userId": 1,
                "completeTime": 400
            },
            {
                "userId":1,
                "completeTime": 600
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I can get the docCount (which is 6) by nested aggregation like this:

```
    BoolQueryBuilder query = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
    query.must(nestedQuery("completeUser", termQuery("completeUser.userId", 1)));   
     BoolQueryBuilder builder = getClient().prepareSearch(getIndexName()).setTypes(getIndexType()).setQuery(query)
                        .addAggregation(AggregationBuilders.nested("nested").path("completeUser")
                                .subAggregation(AggregationBuilders.count("count").field("completeUser.userId"))).setSize(0);
   SearchResponse searchResponse = getSearchResponse(builder);
   Nested nested = searchResponse.getAggregations().get("nested");
    long docCount = nested.getDocCount();  // the docCount is 6
```

but there are still only 2 documents in the searchResponse :

```
SearchRequestBuilder builder = getClient().prepareSearch(getIndexName()).setTypes(getIndexType())
                .setSearchType(SearchType.QUERY_THEN_FETCH).setQuery(query).setFrom(0).setSize(5); // the size is 5
builder.addSort(SortBuilders.fieldSort("completeUser.completeTime")
                    .setNestedFilter(FilterBuilders.termFilter("completeUser.userId", 1))
                    .order(SortOrder.DESC));
SearchResponse searchResponse = getSearchResponse(builder);
```

But what I want is duplicate documents based on completeTime.

How can I get 5 (the value of size) documents in the searchResponse order by the completeTime?

Oh, yes. ElasticSearch version is 1.4.5

Answer (score 0):

Since you have only two documents stored in the index (or at least there are two documents that match your query), those two documents will be returned to you within `SearchResponse`. You can not directly get the first five nested documents sorted by `completeTime` as search response contains whole objects that are stored in the index.

The solution for you would be to parse the results out in java code:

- Since you set the query size to 5, you will get at max five results back, sorted by highest `completeTime` first. That means that you do receive all the needed data and then some more
- Parse all of the nested documents in java, then sort them again and take the first five of them